# Detect link in string and insert anchor tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

```
let string = "This is some text, this [should be a link](https://www.google.com.ar)";
```

like markdown, but I don't want to use a whole markdown library cause the links are the only things I should look for.

this string above should generate this:

```
"This is some text, this <a href="https://www.google.com.ar" target="_blank">should be a link</a>"
```

Edit: to be more precise, I don't want to use a markdown parse because I don't to replace all the other markdown stuff, just the links.

Comment: You could google for "regexp backreference" this will help you :-)

Comment: Someone already posted an answer, but thanks anyway!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a RegExp to replace the text with an anchor tag like this:

```js
let string = "This is some text, this [should be a link](https://www.google.com.ar)";

console.log(      
  string.replace(/\[.*?\]\(.*?\)/g, text => {
    let [fullmatch, name, link] = /\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g.exec(text)
    return `<a href="${link}">${name}</a>`
  })      
)
```

Im not an expert in RegExp so it could be better i guess